# Camera.open() error -13 on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-camera

I've been trying  develop a custom camera application for my project. I have followed pretty much every steps on the android developers website for the deprecated `android.hardware.Camera` class, as I need to stay compatible for older devices. I have added the permission for the camera and the features for the camera and the autofocus. I am currently testing with the emulator provided by android studio, the Nexus 5 API 23 x86 with both front-facing and back-facing cameras set on emulated. When my code reaches the `Camera.open()` bit, I get the error -13: `Fail to connect to camera service`.
I moved my camera initialization at many places but it always throws that error and returns null. The built-in Camera app in the emulator does work properly for both camera and they are both detected in my code. I simply cannot find why it doesn't work.
Here's my code just in case:

CameraActivity.java

```
/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;

    private View mControlsView;
    private boolean mVisible;
    private CameraView mCameraView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);

        mCameraView = new CameraView(this);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        preview.addView(mCameraView);

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mCameraView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.capture_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);

        //// TODO: 2015-11-05 Create a preview class extending SurfaceView and implementing SurfaceHolder.callback and put camera code there
        //// TODO: 2015-11-05 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera
        //// TODO: 2015-11-05 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305107/how-to-fix-fail-to-connect-to-camera-service-exception-in-android-emulator
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mCameraView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mCameraView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mCameraView.releaseCamera();
    }

}
```

CameraView.java

```
import android.hardware.Camera; //This is the good import!

/**
 * TODO: document your custom view class.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        try{
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("CameraView", "Error creating camera: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try{
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("surfaceCreated", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)
            return;

        try{
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Non-existent o.O
        }

        //Resize, etc

        try{
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("CameraView", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if(mCamera != null)
            mCamera.stopPreview();
    }

    public void releaseCamera(){
        if(mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The logcat:

```
11-09 14:13:13.144 7791-7791/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-09 14:13:13.144 7791-7791/? I/art: Late-enabling JIT
11-09 14:13:13.146 7791-7791/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-09 14:13:13.212 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol-1/lib/x86
11-09 14:13:13.427 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
11-09 14:13:13.427 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/CameraView: Error creating camera: Fail to connect to camera service
11-09 14:13:13.489 7791-7820/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-09 14:13:13.508 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab645030, tid 7791
11-09 14:13:13.584 7791-7820/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab6451c0, tid 7820
11-09 14:13:13.611 7791-7820/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-09 14:13:13.693 7791-7820/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-09 14:13:13.693 7791-7820/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabdff9a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol, PID: 7791
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(android.view.SurfaceHolder)' on a null object reference
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol.CameraView.surfaceCreated(CameraView.java:43)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:582)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:177)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2055)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-09 14:13:13.699 7791-7791/com.weebly.olipro007.cameracontrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-09 14:13:16.909 7791-7791/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7791 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the service was completely blocked for the old api in Marshmallow. I switched the emulator to lollipop and it loads...